# Can any bounded area defined by polynomial inequality in $\mathbb{R}^n$ be partitioned into simply connected finite area such that

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

Can any bounded area defined by  polynomial inequality in $\mathbb{R}^n$  be partitioned into simply connected finite areas such that for each simply finite area there exist a diffeomorphic map that maps the area to a m-sphere? Bounded means  the area $A<\infty$  with the boundary defined by the  polynomials. To partition means to partition with k-dimension manifold($k=m-1$) as boundary(the intersection of the two subset) .

Comment: What does "partitioned" mean? A disjoint union? (This clearly can't happen.) An open cover?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, thank you, I will edit it to clarify the question.

Comment: I still don't understand the question. The $n$-sphere cannot even immerse into $\mathbb{R}^n$. Did you mean the $n-1$-sphere, or maybe the $n$-disk?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, thank you for your patience. Let me give a example in 1-dimension, $\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_a^c f(x)dx+\int_c^b f(x)dx $, [a,b] is partitioned into [a,c],[c,b].

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, Sorry, a mistake, thank you again, let me edit again.

Comment: it is well-known that any semialgebraic set can be triangulated. The question you ask seems like a particular case of this fact.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See for instance:

S.  Łojasiewicz, *Triangulation of semi-analytic sets*, Ann. Scuola Norm. Sup. di Pisa, ser. 3, 18.4 (1964), pp. 449–474,

or start a search with the key-words "**Triangulation**" and "**semi-algebraic**", for more recent results, or more suitable to your needs.

Comment: Thank you, I will read the article, and search with the keywords.

Comment: Actually there is a lot of material online. Chapter 3 of these notes: http://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/michel.coste/polyens/SAG.pdf

Comment: Yes, I have just found a lot of material online. Thank you again.